# How to add zooming to chart D3 JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I have this [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3M8V1qa1QABV4ougXMYF?p=preview) and I'm trying to add zooming functionality with the following code as in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708):

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, 10])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("#vis").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .call(zoom);

function zoomed() {
    svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

But my chart doesn't zoom.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you put this jsfiddle?

Comment: @xhulio you can see the demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/3M8V1qa1QABV4ougXMYF?p=preview

Comment: try to add a button there which on click will call the zoom method. as far as i can see your code is ok. just there's no way how to zoom it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that svg doesn't capture mouse events on a group unless there is a visual element present. You can see this for yourself by listening for a simple `click` event on the group (instead of `call(zoom)`). The `click` event will never be fired.

In the d3 example, Mike Bostock adds a rect that is the width and height of the svg to work around this, and you can do something similar.

Here is a zoomable Plunker with that placeholder rect: http://plnkr.co/edit/N3WXCEkYpNgMflWmG8e4?p=preview

Here is the relevant code:

```
var svg = d3.select("#vis").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .classed('transform-target', true)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .call(zoom);

svg.append("rect")
    .style('fill', 'transparent')
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```

You should be able to zoom in and out using doubleclick or scroll.